# F# Sum of products of an array with element position

Tags: arrays, f#

Coming of a C# background and trying to learn F#.
I'm trying to iterate over an array of size 256, so the total sum of it be the product of the element position and the element, like this:

```cs
float sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    sum += i * arr[i];
}
```

I made this but I don't know if this is the best way to do it in F#, probably not.

```ml
let mutable sum = 0
for i in 0 .. 255 do
    sum <- sum + i * arr.[i]
done
```

I don't know if it's possible to use `Array.fold` or `Array.iteri` to solve this in a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapi` and `sum`:

```
let f s = s |> Seq.mapi (fun i j -> i * j) |> Seq.sum
```

Comment: @LDcr `Array` module also has `mapi` function as well as `sum`. Just FYI :)

Comment: Thanks, I did some tests
and the code I made has an increase in performance 
http://pastebin.com/LWByEu3e

And the F# way gives a Numeric overflow if I make an array with 1 .. 1900 elements.
Maybe I have some error in the evaluation code I posted, someone please verify if you can.

Comment: @Lee: Even shorter: `let f = Seq.mapi (*) >> Seq.sum`

Comment: @LDcr: Your loop results in `sum1 = -2008634596` for 1900 elements, that is, it's using unchecked math. `Array.sum` uses checked. If you `open Checked` your loop will overflow also.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this with only one iteration through the array:

```
let f s = snd (Array.fold (fun (i, sum) x -> (i + 1, sum + x * float i)) (0, 0.0) s)
```

Although I prefer Lee's solution as being much easier to follow.

An alternative would be to write your own Array.foldi function and use that.